# Passing a SELECT-OPTIONS table as a parameter to a subroutine?

Tags: parameters, abap, sap-selection-screens

So i have this:

`SELECT-OPTIONS gr_saord FOR gv_sales_order OBLIGATORY.`

then

`PERFORM check_values CHANGING gr_saord.`

then

`FORM check_values  CHANGING p_gr_saord TYPE selopt.`

What i also tried was instead of the structure `SELOPT` to use the Table Type `piq_selopt_t` and instead of passing `gr_saord` to pass `gr_saord[]`.

The presented version of the code and the alternative result both in the same error message:

> in PERFORM or CALL FUNCTION "CHECK_VALUES", the actual parameter
>   "GS_SAORD" is incompatible with the formal parameter "P_GR_SAORD".

Basically i want to simply pass a `SELECT-OPTIONS` table as a parameter and can't manage to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because selopt and piq_selopt_t are not for vbak-vbeln.  Low and High are typed differently in those data types compared to your select option.

This should work

```
data: gv_sales_order type vbap-vbeln.

types: tr_vbeln like RANGE OF gv_sales_order.

SELECT-OPTIONS: gs_saord for gv_sales_order.


perform check_values CHANGING gs_saord[].

form check_values CHANGING p_gr_saord TYPE tr_vbeln.

endform.
```

Comment: After i confirm it, you'll get the +1 and i'll accept the answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lazy (and have a lot select options to pass) and you onyl need to pass them to a select statement within your FORM, you can skip the type definition and define you form with

```
perform check_values CHANGING gs_saord[].

form check_values CHANGING p_gr_saord TYPE standard table.

endform.
```

Comment: i'm scared of not typing things properly - i'm an ex java guy :)